non-upsampled out-of-bag predictions despite up-sampling using R's RandomForest via caret
There are many questions and answers on how to access the OOB predictions from the randomForest package, e.g. here
However, I could not find anything about how to do this properly when using randomForest via caret whilst making use of caret's up-sampling functionality for classification.
Here is a silly example which illustrates that the number of OOB predictions you are getting from the predicted output matches the number of input rows if you directly use randomForest or use it via caret (as long as you do not sample up). But as soon as you use up-sampling you are getting more values than you had rows in your training data.
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

input.train=mtcars
input.train$cyl <- as.factor(input.train$cyl) #create factor for classification task
x <- input.train[, names(input.train)!="cyl"]
y <- input.train[, names(input.train)=="cyl"]

rf <- randomForest(x=x,y=y,keep.forest=TRUE,keep.inbag=TRUE)
predcited.rf <- as.data.frame(rf$predicted) # documentation: "the predicted values of the input data based on out-of-bag samples"

tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=c(5,7)) # some random tune values, doesn't really matter here
cntrl_a <- trainControl(method = "oob", number=5, sampling="up", search="grid", verboseIter=TRUE, savePredictions=TRUE, seeds=NULL, allowParallel = FALSE) #training with up-sampling
cntrl_b <- trainControl(method = "oob", number=5, search='grid', verboseIter=TRUE, savePredictions=TRUE, seeds=NULL, allowParallel = FALSE) #training without up-sampling
rf.caret_a <- caret::train(x=x, y=y, method="rf", trControl=cntrl_a, tuneGrid=tunegrid, importance=TRUE)
rf.caret_b <- caret::train(x=x, y=y, method="rf", trControl=cntrl_b, tuneGrid=tunegrid, importance=TRUE)

predcited.rf.caret_a <- as.data.frame(rf.caret_a$finalModel$predicted)
predcited.rf.caret_b <- as.data.frame(rf.caret_b$finalModel$predicted)

print(nrow(input.train)) #row count training data
print(length(rf$predicted)) #count oob prediction values from random forest
print(length(rf.caret_a$finalModel$predicted)) #count oob prediction values from caret w/ up-sampling
print(length(rf.caret_b$finalModel$predicted)) #count oob prediction values from caret w/o up-sampling

While this kind of makes sense, does anyone know a trick how to get the oob predictions in the same row order and with the same row count as the training data before up-sampling?
Thanks!
